# Entity Framework error on update: The property 'NewsId' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight

I'm getting the following error in a Silverlight web application whenever I try to update **ANYTHING** in Silverlight:

> The property 'NewsId' is part of the object's key information and
>   cannot be modified.

You can substitute out `NewsId` for the primary key of whatever table I'm trying to update (`SalesID`, `OrdersID`...etc).

The strange thing is that I have a primary key setup on EVERY single table and that primary key is only on one column (`SalesId`, `NewsID`, `OrderId`..etc.), so I'm not sure why it would be trying to update the primary key on an update.

My code to update the data is:

```
public void UpdateNews(News currentNews)
{
      this.ObjectContext.News.AttachAsModified(currentNews, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentNews));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Look at `currentNews.NewsId` and `this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentNews).NewsId` in debugger

Comment: I checked in the debugger and nothing is returned from this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentNews). I'm thinking because nothing is being returned it assumes everything in the table needs updated which is why it's including the Primary Key to be updated.